# find mulitple users by email in rails or postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to update multiple users attributes all at once. Is there a way in rails to find multiple users by email? for example User.find_by_email(joe@example.com, tom@example.com) I write this in the heroku console and it does not work. I know in rails the find method accepts an array of numbers for the id I was hoping the same for email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`User.find_all_by_email( ["joe@example.com", "tom@example.com"] )`

Comment: Quick note: The "find_all_by_*" syntax returns an array of your results, where as the "where" syntax in weexpectedTHIS's solution return an ActiveRecord Relation

Answer (score 3):

Proper syntax in rails 3 would be this:

```
User.where(:email => ["joe@example.com", "tom@example.com"])
```